# adding a VARCHAR to DATE as MINUTES

Tags: sql, db2, dashdb

I'm pretty sure this is an easy one for you guys but it's driving me crazy.
I have a column with dates in a "YYYY-MM-DD" format and a column with small intergers values between 0 and 29. So I want to add the 2 columns together and get something like this:

```
Date        | INT |  NEW timestamp  
2016-01-01  |  2  |  2016-01-01  00:02:00  
2016-10-15  | 21  |  2015-10-15  00:21:00
```

so I tried the obvious like:

```
"Date" + "INT" as "NEW timestamp"
```

and stuff like

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT("INT",'MI')
```

or even

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT("Date",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  + VARCHAR_FORMAT("INT",'MI')
```

but keep getting errors. I am doing this in dashDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use:

```
select add_minutes(cast("date" as timestamp),"int") from yourTable
```

Another simple version is:

```
select cast("date" as timestamp) + "int" minutes from yourTable
```

Comment: cast("date" as timestamp) doesn't work on db2 iseries

Answer (score 0):

On db2 iseries

```
 select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') + INT minute as Newtimestamp from yourtable
```

or

```
 select cast(cast(Date as date) as timestamp) + int minute from yourtable
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
Date_add(cast(`Date` as date),interval Int minute)
```